# Clickhouse - Alias in view

Tags: view, clickhouse

I would like create view with alias in SELECT query.
After try with this syntax it's not work.
Clickhouse don't support alias in view query or my syntax is bad ?

Error message:

> Received exception from server (version 20.3.5): Code: 352.
>   DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot
>   detect left and right JOIN keys. JOIN ON section is ambiguous..

Error message if i drop alias in JOIN (ON A.column1 = B.column1 ---> ON table_a.column1 = table_b.column1):

> Received exception from server (version 20.3.5): Code: 47.
>   DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Missing
>   columns:

Create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_a
(
    `column1` Nullable(Int32),
    `column2` Nullable(Int32),
    `column3` Nullable(Int32),
    `column4` Nullable(Int32)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY tuple()
order by tuple();


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_b
(
    `column1` Nullable(Int32),
    `column2` Nullable(Int32),
    `column3` Nullable(Int32),
    `column4` Nullable(Int32)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY tuple()
order by tuple();
```

View query:

```sql
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS view_table_AB AS 
SELECT
A.column1,
A.column2,
A.column3,
A.column4,

B.column1,
B.column2,
B.column3,
B.column4
FROM table_a AS A
INNER JOIN table_b AS B ON A.column1 = B.column1;
```

DOC clickhouse: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/fr/sql-reference/syntax/#syntax-expression_aliases

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you provide more information? Can you post the type of the columns and the foreign key constraints?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on CH 20.3.8.53. Try this query: *create view if not exists view_01 AS select D.name, D.engine, C.table, C.name, C.type from system.columns AS C inner join system.databases AS D ON C.database = D.name* - is is work for you?

Comment: He have not primary and foreign key

Comment: @vladimir i test

Comment: @vladimir your query work

Comment: @M46 i have edit my question with create table

Comment: @vladimir why your query works ? i don't understand

Comment: @vladimir primary and foreign key is mandatory for use alias ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is the bug. I added [CH Issue 11000](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11000), let's wait for the answer.

As workaround need to specify database-prefix instead of aliases:

```sql
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS view_table_AB AS 
SELECT
    table_a.column1,
    table_a.column2,
    table_a.column3,
    table_a.column4,

    table_b.column1,
    table_b.column2,
    table_b.column3,
    table_b.column4
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.column1 = table_b.column1;
```